# Error 2032 :stream Error while loading flex application

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flexbuilder

I have a flex application and build as war file and deployed in jboss server. Some times application is loading and working fine but sometimes am getting 2032: Stream error while loading it.

Temporary solution i did as i copied framework_4.1.0.16067.SWZ file from the sdk and copied inthe war file explicitly. after doing this ,application loading as usaul and no errors will display.

Am looking for permanent solution for this issue.

Comment: The .SWZ files are runtime shared libraries (RSL's) that are downloaded from Adobe (or now from Apache, I guess). It could be a problem on the other end, and the problem might just go away. One solution is not to use RSL's at all. This will make the size of your application SWF bigger, however. In Flash Builder you can change this in the project properties. Your current solution might be preferable, but it depends on where the RSL's come from (Adobe or Apache Flex). Prior to Apache FLex, the signed RSL's from Adobe could be cached by Flash player.

Comment: @SunilD The swz files are digitally signed versions of the SDK that the Flash Player can cache across domains. Adobe is not willing to digitally sign SWFs they didn't create; and as such the Apache Flex cannot provide SWZ files that will be cached across domains; and as such RSLs won't be downloaded from Apache. [Although I have the gist right; I may have details wrong]

Comment: @Reboog711 since he is using Flex 4.1 (based on RSL filename), would that imply he would get the signed RSL from Adobe?

Comment: @SunilD. Correct! I was explicitly responding to your comment "downloaded from Adobe (or now from Apache, I guess)".  Apache Flex won't be able to offer swz file that are cached across domains; and I believe there is no way to download a framework swz from an Apache domain.